# Issue NestJS with oracle TypeORM

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to connect my NestJs Project with a Oracle db and I'm using TypeORM and the status of connection is ok but I don't know how I can connect with a function. This function is into of a package and at the same time this package is into of a schema. The structure is like:

mySchema:
--------->myPackage:
-------------------->myFunction(id)

In the NestJS code I'm define this import in the AppModule file:

[image]

When I try to use the entity I don't know what method can I use to connect with my function. With the ESLint I get the next methods:

[image]

I hope to be clear and thanks for all!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "connect with a function". What's this function do? What's the purpose of it? Is it a JavaScript/Typescript function, or a SQL function in your database?

Comment: The function is in my Oracle database, this function is in a package and this package is in a schema. The function receive a string param and return a status code.

Comment: The function is in your database but is in a js package? I don't follow. Can you show some sort of related code?

Comment: I have a Schema named sysadm in oracle DB (PL SQL) in this schema I have a package named UTILITARIO_BSCS_PKG and into the this package I have a function named FNC_CONSULTAR_CUSTCODE_SS. I need access to this function from NestJS

Answer (score 0):

In you last picture you’re trying to make a request to the database and as you can see, when you mentioned the `testRepository` and dots(.) now you have to tell him what you want to do in your database and in the suggested list you have all the possible  possibilities.

So if you want  to get or fetch data from you database, you will use `testRepository.find()` this will give you everything in that particular entity. To do that, you have to do something like below, before that you code has something that I have never seen in Nest, (public); if it does exist  but I won’t use that in my Example since I don’t know  it in Nest and also; you have started writing without (return) I don’t know  how you’re expecting to return what you will  get from your database.

Here is my example:

---

in your controller:

```js
@Get() AnyThing(): Promise<TestEntity[]> {return this.DaobscsService.whatEver(); }
```

And in your service:

```js
@InjectRepository(TestEntity) private readonlytestRepository: Repository<TestEntity>, ) {}

async whatEver(): Promise<TestEntity[]> {return await this.testRepository.find();}
```

---

What ever name you gonna use instead (whatEver()) in the service  that have used, remember to use the same name  in your controller pointing to service (this.Boa...Service.(The name here) OOP system’s you know it I hope

This example is to get or fetch so if you don’t have any thing in your database then you will get nothing! if that’s not what u want then command with a full version of what exactly is your issue, what u expected and code from controller, service, and module.